# Get top n values with too few values

Tags: sorting, error-handling, excel-2010

Suppose I have a range of 10 cells, A1 to J1, which will contain numbers, and I want to get the average of the largest 3. I can do this with:

```
=AVERAGE(LARGE(A1:J1,{1,2,3}))
```

The only issue is if there are less than 3 value. In this event I get a Number Error.

I would like to handle this so that if there are less than 3 non-blank cells in my range (can be checked with `ISBLANK`), for example only 2, it should instead average only those 2 or however many.

Is it possible to do this easily?

Answer (score 0):

You could use IFERROR like this

`=IFERROR(AVERAGE(LARGE(A1:J1,{1,2,3})),AVERAGE(A1:J1))`

That will average all the values (1 or 2) if there are fewer than 3

You can add another IFERROR if you want to cater for the scenario where A1:J1 is entirely unpopulated, i.e.

`=IFERROR(IFERROR(AVERAGE(LARGE(A1:J1,{1,2,3})),AVERAGE(A1:J1)),0)`

that will return zero (rather than #DIV/0!)

Answer (score 0):

Try this - it's simple but it works

```
=IF(COUNT(A1:J1) >= 3,AVERAGE(LARGE(A1:J1,{1,2,3})),  
                      IF(COUNT(A1:J1)>=2,AVERAGE(LARGE(A1:J1,{1,2})),  
                                         IF(COUNT(A1:J1) = 1, MAX(A1:J1),"Too few numbers")))
```